# Groovy sorting string asc

Tags: groovy, sorting

How to sort string names in array on ascending order .

I tried sort method  but it fails to sort on name basis .

def words = ["orange", "blue", "apple", "violet", "green"]

I need to achieve like this :

["apple", "blue", "green", "orange", "violet" ]

thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you please accept me if you're satisfied with my answer? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
["orange", "blue", "apple", "violet", "green"].sort()
```

Comment: hi chrsk, you saved my time.

Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1):

```
def words = ["orange", "blue", "apple", "violet", "green"]

["orange", "blue", "apple", "violet", "green"].sort({ a, b -> a[0] <=> b[0] } as Comparator )
```

You can also change the indexes based on the requirement